# VTK Image Data, access 1 image in an array

Tags: c++, image, vtk

If I have vtkImageData of size 100x100x5, is there a quick way of getting the 3rd image in the array (i.e. the 3rd 100x100 image in the 5 image array)? All I have found so far is:

```
   uint16_t* newIm = static_cast<uint16_t*>(newImData->GetScalarPointer());  
   uint16_t* num;
   int index = 0;
   int frameNum = 3;
    for (int y = col-1; y >= 0 ; y--)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            num =  static_cast<uint16_t*>(imData->GetScalarPointer(x,y,frameNum));
            newIm[index] = num[0];
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Where imData comes from a different function in my program. 
I'm trying to avoid the double `for` loop because its not very efficient. Does VTK have an easier way of copying the 3rd 100x100 element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `vtkExtractVOI` filter to extract out a subsection of your vtkImageData.  Note that although you are thinking of your image as 5 100x100 images, in VTK it is a single 5x100x100 3-d image.

To select a 2-d Z slice out of a 3-d image, you'd do something like this:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkExtractVOI> extractVOI =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkExtractVOI>::New();

extractVOI->SetInputConnection(source->GetOutputPort());

extractVOI>SetVOI(0, row-1, 0, col-1, z, z);

extractVOI->Update();

vtkImageData* extracted = extractVOI->GetOutput();
```

See this ExtractVOI example and the vtkExtractVOI documentation:
https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/ImageData/ExtractVOI
https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkExtractVOI.html